# Identify highly fragmented indexes and rebuild for single database/table SQL Server 2005/2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for a script that will identify highly fragmented indexes on a single DB, and optionally a single table as I think `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` is quite resource intensive.

Also with the option of making the table offline?  I read this is possible somewhere?

Comment: FYI, StackOverflow isn't a custom query/coding house where you can ask for someone to write you a complicated stored procedure.  It's best to start off by describing what you have tried, what errors you encountered, etc.  If you want someone to write code to your spec you are best off hiring a consultant or contractor.

Comment: Yes in an ideal world I would just go off and hire a contractor.  Unfortunately in the real world this is not always possible.  I'm asking a technical question which is exactly what this site is designed for which also helps other users.  I need to query the sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats for fragmentation higher than 30%. Then rebuild indexes where fragmentation > %30.  This is not a complicated task but I do not know the syntax to do it.  That's why i'm on this site asking the question.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be rude, but it's normally best to offer up what you have tried instead of just saying "I need something that does this"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one from MSDN:

```
--This example shows a simple way to defragment all indexes in a database that is fragmented above a declared threshold.

/*Perform a 'USE <database name>' to select the database in which to run the script.*/
-- Declare variables
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR (128)
DECLARE @execstr   VARCHAR (255)
DECLARE @objectid  INT
DECLARE @indexid   INT
DECLARE @frag      DECIMAL
DECLARE @maxfrag   DECIMAL

-- Decide on the maximum fragmentation to allow
SELECT @maxfrag = 30.0

-- Declare cursor
DECLARE tables CURSOR FOR
   SELECT TABLE_NAME
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE #fraglist (
   ObjectName CHAR (255),
   ObjectId INT,
   IndexName CHAR (255),
   IndexId INT,
   Lvl INT,
   CountPages INT,
   CountRows INT,
   MinRecSize INT,
   MaxRecSize INT,
   AvgRecSize INT,
   ForRecCount INT,
   Extents INT,
   ExtentSwitches INT,
   AvgFreeBytes INT,
   AvgPageDensity INT,
   ScanDensity DECIMAL,
   BestCount INT,
   ActualCount INT,
   LogicalFrag DECIMAL,
   ExtentFrag DECIMAL)

-- Open the cursor
OPEN tables

-- Loop through all the tables in the database
FETCH NEXT
   FROM tables
   INTO @tablename

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
-- Do the showcontig of all indexes of the table
   INSERT INTO #fraglist 
   EXEC ('DBCC SHOWCONTIG (''' + @tablename + ''') 
      WITH FAST, TABLERESULTS, ALL_INDEXES, NO_INFOMSGS')
   FETCH NEXT
      FROM tables
      INTO @tablename
END

-- Close and deallocate the cursor
CLOSE tables
DEALLOCATE tables

-- Declare cursor for list of indexes to be defragged
DECLARE indexes CURSOR FOR
   SELECT ObjectName, ObjectId, IndexId, LogicalFrag
   FROM #fraglist
   WHERE LogicalFrag >= @maxfrag
      AND INDEXPROPERTY (ObjectId, IndexName, 'IndexDepth') > 0

-- Open the cursor
OPEN indexes

-- loop through the indexes
FETCH NEXT
   FROM indexes
   INTO @tablename, @objectid, @indexid, @frag

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Executing DBCC INDEXDEFRAG (0, ' + RTRIM(@tablename) + ',
      ' + RTRIM(@indexid) + ') - fragmentation currently '
       + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(15),@frag)) + '%'
   SELECT @execstr = 'DBCC INDEXDEFRAG (0, ' + RTRIM(@objectid) + ',
       ' + RTRIM(@indexid) + ')'
   EXEC (@execstr)

   FETCH NEXT
      FROM indexes
      INTO @tablename, @objectid, @indexid, @frag
END

-- Close and deallocate the cursor
CLOSE indexes
DEALLOCATE indexes

-- Delete the temporary table
DROP TABLE #fraglist
GO
```

Comment: thanks for this... how is this different to rebuilding the indexes?  I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to SQL indexing... I just saw that for less than 30% you reorganise and over 30% rebuild.

Comment: See here for differences between reorg and rebuild.  http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/02/07/index-rebuilding-vs-index-reorganizing-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: Here is another script which seems to be more selective about reorg or rebuilding the indexes, it may suit your needs . http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/15/a-more-effective-selective-index-rebuildreorganize-strategy/

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't use `DBCC INDEXDEFRAG`. Instead, you should use something like `ALTER INDEX myindex ON mytable REBUILD with(ONLINE=ON)` (the `with(ONLINE=ON)` is an Enterprise Edition feature when doing this while your database is live)

Comment: It works better if you replace "TABLE_NAME" in the SELECT command with '[' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + ']' because if your tables are not in dbo schema the script will not work.

Answer (score 4):

run this query :

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(DMV.object_id) AS TABLE_NAME ,
    SI.NAME AS INDEX_NAME ,
    avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS FRAGMENT_PERCENT ,
    DMV.record_count
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SAMPLED')
    AS DMV
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS.INDEXES AS SI ON DMV.OBJECT_ID = SI.OBJECT_ID
                                         AND DMV.INDEX_ID = SI.INDEX_ID
WHERE   avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 10
    AND index_type_desc IN ( 'CLUSTERED INDEX', 'NONCLUSTERED INDEX' )
    AND DMV.record_count >= 2000
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC
```

And all index that have `FRAGMENT_PERCENT` over 30% most rebuild.

Comment: If someone gets 'Incorrect syntax near ')'' look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878027/incorrect-syntax-near-when-checking-index-fragmentation

Answer (score -1):

This code will generate rebuild code when `Frag > Target`. Run as step 1 of job to generate code you run as step 2
 (I have learned from all of you and added my bit. :-)

EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb "USE [?]; SELECT 'use '+DB_NAME(db_id())+';' SELECT 'ALTER INDEX [' 
        + SI.NAME + '] ON [' + OBJECT_NAME(DMV.object_id) + '] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE=ON);'
        +'-- Fragmentation: '+convert(varchar(40),avg_fragmentation_in_percent )
    FROM    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SAMPLED')   DMV
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS.INDEXES AS SI ON DMV.OBJECT_ID = SI.OBJECT_ID
                                         AND DMV.INDEX_ID = SI.INDEX_ID
    WHERE   avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 29
      AND index_type_desc IN ( 'CLUSTERED INDEX', 'NONCLUSTERED INDEX' )
      AND DMV.record_count >= 2000
    ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(DMV.object_id), SI.NAME "