# Incorrect syntax near '(' when checking index fragmentation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to check index fragmentation in my database using SQL 2008 R2.

I'm using the following code, taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189858(v=sql.100).aspx with a couple of name changes:

```
USE StockSystem;
GO
SELECT a.index_id, name, avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.StockItems'),NULL, NULL, NULL) AS a
JOIN sys.indexes AS b ON a.object_id = b.object_id AND a.index_id = b.index_id;
```

GO

When I run it I get the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

### UPDATE

Weird thing is, if I call the two functions (DB_ID and OBJECT_ID) and get the values, then substitute the values in the main select statement, it all works fine. Why can't I seemingly use the two functions within the SELECT, as per MSDN?

### UPDATE

In response to Akrem's sugegstion, I also tried this but get the same error.

```
USE StockSystem;
GO
SELECT a.index_id, name, avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID('StockSystem'), OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.StockItems'), NULL, NULL, NULL) AS a
JOIN sys.indexes AS b ON a.object_id = b.object_id AND a.index_id = b.index_id;
```

### UPDATE

Sorry for all the updates. I've tried the same query on a SQL2012 system with a copy of the database. This works without a problem. I've also tried the same statement but with different names on a different database but on the same SQL instance. This works too.

I guess it's a problem with the database then so I've restored a copy into a test SQL instance. Running the index stats for this restored copy has the same problem. As this is a production database that the company can't be without I'm limited in what else I can try.

Any ideas anyone?

### UPDATE

OK, this is weird. If I take the DB_ID and OBJECT_ID out of the statement the batch runs perfectly.

```
use StockSystem

declare @dbid SMALLINT
declare @objectid INT

select @dbid = DB_ID('StockSystem'), @objectid = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.StockItems')

SELECT a.index_id,name,avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (@dbid,@objectid,NULL,NULL,NULL) AS a
JOIN sys.indexes AS b ON a.object_id = b.object_id AND a.index_id = b.index_id;
```

Comment: Is this the exact query you have, seems correct.

Comment: Exact query, copied in from SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Nope, if I copy and paste this code, it runs fine, are you sure there aren't any stray characters in your query window?  If you double click the error message, it will highlight the line with the problem.

Comment: I've tried your query on different systems (2005,2008,2012) and it's working fine. Are you sure this exact query is giving you error?

Comment: I tried a new query window and retyped manually, as well as copying in from the question above. Still the same error :(

Comment: try without N - OBJECT_ID('dbo.StockItems')

Comment: @Nenad - same error without the N

Comment: What compatibility level is the database?

Comment: @ta.speot.is - Interesting. It's set to 'SQL Server 2000 (80)'. Not sure why - I've inherited this system.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- [Unexpected errors from table-valued functions](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/20/unexpected-errors-from-table-valued-functions)

Your database is probably set with compatibility level 80 (SQL Server 2000) and DB_ID and OBJECT_ID functions can not be used as a parameter for dynamic management function.

You should either change compatibility level to something newer or use variables before query:

```
USE StockSystem;
GO
DECLARE
    @database_id INT = DB_ID(),
    @object_id   INT = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.StockItems');

SELECT a.index_id, name, avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (@database_id ,@object_id , NULL, NULL, NULL) AS a
JOIN sys.indexes AS b ON a.object_id = b.object_id AND a.index_id = b.index_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the name of database

```
DB_ID("DataBaseName")
```

**update :**

please try this and told as if it work

```
USE StockSystem;
GO
select  * from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(),null,null,null,null)
```

Comment: Hmm. That isn't what's in the article on MSDN. Anyway, I tried it and I get the same error. I'll update the question with the code copied in again.

Comment: I've added to the question. All sorts of weirdness.